# My SQL Query does not work, but returns no error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a `UPDATE` SQL query in a PHP script but the query always returns a null or empty error. I am not sure why this is happening. Here is my code so far:

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
}

$query = "UPDATE Products SET FilePrice=".$ourprice." WHERE FileID=".$id;
$sql = mysql_query($query);
if ($sql === TRUE) {
    echo "Price Modified Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn1->error;
}
```

Every time I run the script it just echoes `Error:`

Does anybody know why this is happening (I do not get a connection error initially either)?

Comment: Its a good opportunity to stop using `mysql_` and begin using PDO or `mysqli_`  since `mysql_`  is deprecated. And you can then start using prepared statements too, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You're using 4 parameters for your connection. That is a `mysqli_` method and not `mysql_`.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` API does not offer OOP syntax so your code is incorrect and will not report an error (actually, if you had error reporting set to display all errors PHP would have thrown an error). Combine that and your use of four parameterrs in `mysql_connect` and it looks you used `mysql` functions after reading a `mysqli` tutorial.

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$conn1 ) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn1 );
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can't use foo : " . mysql_error());
}

$query = "UPDATE Products SET FilePrice=".$ourprice." WHERE FileID=".$id;
$sql = mysql_query($query);
if ($sql === TRUE) {
    echo "Price Modified Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error();
}
```

This doesn't fix your UPDATE issue but will tell you what error MySQL is reporting.

(Your error is probably due to `$ourprice` being empty so check that next).

Comment: Si signore. Plus, OP is using 4 parameters in connection ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- as always, nice catch.

Comment: It's close to dinner time. Hunger makes me leaner and meaner ;-)

Comment: Will mark as correct when I can. Also, I'm not sure why I got -3'd for a question that was clearly answer-able.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ...and now I'm hungry!

Comment: @Fred-ii- You ate better than I. And I had a craving for a burger earlier today, too. Now I *really* want one....

Comment: @JohnConde Actually, it was a *cheese* burger, with only a couple of slices of tomatoes; *yummo*. Nothing like *tasting* the meat and not masking it with condiments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- truer words have never been spoken.

Comment: @JohnConde First time I had a ketchup-less burger, was when my brother had a BBQ about 8 years ago, made a burger with seasoned/marinaded beef, and I asked him if he had ketchup. He told me "hey, try it without it and if you don't like it, I'll get you some." - Well John, he was right. It made all the difference. Rightly prepared, one doesn't need any condiments on a *good* burger, maybe just a tomato, lettuce and onions. I just like a nice thick juicy slice of tomato; *garden* tomatoes are even better. Try it sometime, if you haven't already ;-)